# Specific Class type parameter in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class

I want to accept a Class object as a parameter to a constructor of one of my classes.  It needs to do a lot of custom work with it, and I want to abstract that away from the user of the class.

For example, let's say my class is a Dealership and I want to initialize it with any type of Vehicle.

So I have the following hierarchy:

```
Dealership : NSObject

Vehicle : NSObject
Truck : Vehicle
Van : Vehicle
Car : Vehicle
```

What I want to do is, inside Dealership, implement the following initializer:

```
- (id)initWithVehicle:(Class)aVehicle;
```

Except instead of accepting a generic Class, I'd like to restrict it to only Classes of type "Vehicle" (which would include all my inherited classes).  I could just test for this property in the initializer, but it would be great if there was a way to enforce this at compile time instead of waiting for runtime feedback.

It seems you can reference Class to restrict to classes that implement a certain interface, so I could do some hackery there.  Is there any way to refer to Class objects of a specific type though?

EDIT - Note that I edited the example classes because the original example was a bit misleading.  The example is just for demonstration purposes, not the actual class hierarchy I'm working with.

Comment: Again, why are you passing the classes themselves rather than instances thereof? Are you using them to produce instances?

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan - Correct.  I don't want the users of this class to have to set up instances to pass into the initializer because there is a lot of detail work that is the same every time.  They shouldn't need to worry about that.  I want them to be able to say "just use a Vehicle of flavor Truck for all the stuff you've got to do".

Comment: I think it is what the objective-c lack of

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at compile-time, but you can release `self` and return `nil` if the class is invalid:

```
- (id)initWithCar: (Class)carClass {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        if (![carClass isSubclassOfClass:[Car class]]) {
            [self release];
            self = nil;
        } else {
            // Normal initialization here.
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

That's the closest you'll get to the sort of restriction you want.

But this sort of design suggests you need to rethink your class hierarchy. Rather than passing a subclass of `Car`, you should have a `Manufacturer` class. Something like this:

```
@interface Manufacturer : NSObject
+ (id)manufacturerWithName: (NSString *)name;

- (NSArray *)allCars;
@property (readonly) Car *bestsellingCar;
// etc.
@end

#define kManufacturerVolvo [Manufacturer manufacturerWithName: @"Volvo"]
#define kManufacturerToyota [Manufacturer manufacturerWithName: @"Toyota"]
// etc.
```

And then this initializer for Dealership:

```
- (id)initWithManufacturer: (Manufacturer *)aManufacturer;
```

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan - Yep, that'd be the runtime solution I spoke of.  Thanks for posting it so people know though, should have spelled it out in the original post.

Comment: @DougW: Take a look at the alternate approach I've suggested. `Toyota` shouldn't be a subclass of `Car`, but a subclass of `Manufacturer`. `Prius` is a subclass of `Car`, via `Hatchback <Hybrid>`. ;)

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan - Re: re-thinking class hierarchy.  You're right, there are ways I could work around this.  The problem is this is already an extensive class hierarchy and would require a lot of rework to use an interface instead.  That said, I don't think there's necessarily anything architecturally wrong with the pattern I'm suggesting.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan - The cars just are a very simplistic example to demonstrate the problem I'm working with.  The real problem is much more extensive, and inheritance is really the right way to go with it imo.  Just too much detail for a question like this.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan - I edited the original question to use a better example class hierarchy.  You're right, manufacturer was a bad example of inheritance.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan - I voted it down myself because at the end of the day it just doesn't answer the question.  I apologize for having to do that, but the algorithm they use to prioritize questions takes into account the vote totals on answers.  I really wish I didn't have to.  I agree it's stupid, and I posted a suggestion on meta to avoid it.  Check it out if you're inclined http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89735/mark-wrong-answers

Comment: Pretty sure it answered your question before you changed it. Actually, it still does--you can't do what you want to do at compile-time.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan - I didn't change the question.  I altered the example to avoid confusion, but the question never changed.  You are right though, it's possible that the answer is "no, you can't".  I'm going to leave it open a bit longer in case there is a solution, but if nobody comes up with one soon I'll happily accept your answer and vote it back up.

Comment: I meant changed as in edited, not "replaced with a different question." :)

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan - Doesn't appear that any other solutions are forthcoming, so I guess this is just not possible as you stated.  Shame, seems like something worthwhile to have in certain cases.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan - Sorry for the spam, but I apparently can't change my vote unless you edit the question (some system).  Make a small change if you care enough.

Comment: `if (![carClass isKindOfClass:[Car class]])` Your code doesn't make sense. `carClass` is going to be an instance of its meta-class, which is not going to be related to the `Car` class

Comment: I'm afraid you're incorrect. `carClass`, assuming it was got via something like `[FordFiesta class]`, is not its own meta-class. The only way you typically get a meta-class is if you ask for it via the Objective-C runtime.

Comment: `carClass`  is kind of `Class`  and it's not an object so you cannot send `-isKindOfClass:`  message to it!

Comment: From the docs: *If the receiver is a class object, this method returns YES if aClass is a Class object of the same type, NO otherwise.*

Comment: Changed it to use `+isSubclassOfClass:` anyway. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can ensure using a protocol check:

```
- (id)initWithVehicle:(id<VehicleProtocol>)aVehicle;
...
}
```

Declaring an object as id tells the compiler that you don't care what type the object is, but you do care that it conforms to the specified VehicleProtocol protocol**.

Comment: I mentioned this potential workaround in the OP.  It is true, and thank you for taking the time to mention it.  It doesn't answer the question at hand though.

Comment: declaring a protocol and using it like this is the solution to this problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what kind of solution you're getting at, but perhaps treating `Vehicle` as a class cluster would enable you to coalesce the common functionality under one umbrella, and have the class cluster manage the different implementations (and mask them from the user)?

For example, `NSString` does this; underlying instances are usually of type `NSCFString`, unless they're literals (i.e. `@"this is a literal, in code"`), in which case they are `NSConstantString`s.

[Here](http://s117161884.onlinehome.us/weblog/make-your-own-abstract-factory-class-cluster-in-objective-c/) is an excerpt from a relevant blog post explaining class clusters:

> In a nutshell, it’s a design that allows you to incorporate a family of functionally-related of objects into your application while keeping the code interacting with those objects loosely coupled, flexible, and easy to maintain or update.
>
> A class cluster conforms this set of common objects to behave according to a single interface and, furthermore, channels all creation of them through that interface. The construction is made up of two key parts: a) one public, abstract interface serving as the “face” of the cluster which advertises the supported API, and b) many private, concrete subclasses of this interface responsible for actually implementing the advertised behavior of the superclass in their own specific way. The abstract superclass does implement a few methods itself, the most significant being a factory method to vend instances of the private subclasses; other common functionality shared across all subclasses, such as accessors, can also be defined here and shared as well.
>
> Users of the cluster only ever see the one public superclass, are unaware that it is actually abstract, and know nothing about the existence of any private concrete subclasses. The superclass offers a factory creational method which is responsible for determining which subclass is appropriate for any given situation and transparently returning an instance of it. Since this returned object implements and behaves according to the public superclass’ interface, users can simply assume they have obtained a direct instance of this superclass.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to init dealership with a vehicle (I mean an initialized instance) you should do:

```
- (id)initWithCar:(Vehicle *)carClass
{
    //An extra check (only for DEBUG mode)
    NSAssert([carClass isKindOfClass:[Vehicle class]]);
    ... //carClass is now a Vehicle instance
}
```