# Is there any reason Apple decided to use AnyClass rather than using UITableViewCell.Type?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, language-design

With the code below, you could potentially pass `UIViewController.self` in for the `cellClass`

```
func register(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

and run into bugs.

However if it was written as:

```
func register(_ cellClass: UITableViewCell.Type?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

Whatever passed has to be a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. It would no longer accept `UIViewController.self`. If passed it would throw an error at compile time, which is better.

So is there any reason why it's not written this way?

<sub>I'm not looking for opinions, just want to know would there be any downside if Apple wrote the way I suggested or are there any language limitations that I'm not aware of?</sub>

Comment: `UITableView` is written in Objective-C

Comment: dan can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: In Objective-C it's `- (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass 
forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;` with the limit in Objective-C https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873911/specific-class-type-parameter-in-objective-c

Comment: @Larme "with the limit in Objective-C"...I don't understand your wording...

Comment: Objective-C doesn't have a way to add restrictions to a `Class` parameter

Comment: @Honey If you read the question (the user want to do "your suggestion" in Objective-C in its own code), and especially the answer, it seems that there is no equivalent to `MyClass.type` to restrict the parameter in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API for UITableView comes from the Objective-C header file. The `cellClass` parameter in Objective-C is simply `Class` with the Swift equivalent being `AnyClass`. Unlike in Swift, Objective-C doesn't support declaring that the value of `Class` (`AnyClass`) be any specific type.

So when this API is translated for Swift, you are left with the generic `AnyClass` in Swift.

It is odd that the documentation doesn't specify that the passed in class/type should be `UITableViewCell` (or a subclass).

This limitation in Objective-C is discussed (thanks Larme) here: [Specific Class type parameter in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873911/specific-class-type-parameter-in-objective-c)